# Error messages in EAFP style

Tags: python, error-handling, styles

"It's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission", or EAFP, is a common style in Python, where the coder writes code expecting an error and uses the error handling for expected flow control.

The problem I often find is that this can lead to confusing error messages. Consider this example.

```
some_dict = {} # oops a bug, this should have 'expected key'

try:
    some_dict['optional key'] # expected error
except KeyError:
    some_dict['expected key'] # unexpected error
```

Which yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eafp.py", line 4, in <module>
    some_dict['optional key'] # expected error
KeyError: 'optional key'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "eafp.py", line 6, in <module>
    some_dict['expected key'] # unexpected error
KeyError: 'expected key'
```

Specifically, the unexpected error message references the expected one. This is a trivial example, but in some situations the first error may be completely expected and un-noteworthy, but seems closely related to the real cause of the error and can cause some confusion.

My question is how best to handle this type of issue. Can the first error message be suppressed? Or modified to something less conspicuous?

Comment: Given that GvR finds full tracebacks so important that he prioritizes them over including default TCO in the language, I'd say that you might want to rethink your plans to suppress parts of tracebacks.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fair comment, modifying tracebacks could get nasty fast. I just wondered if there is a common idiom or solution for these situations.

Comment: My point isn't that the process would be nasty or difficult (although it probably would be, by design) - it's that the common idiom is to have a full traceback. Unless there's an actual, specific problem with having the expected error message appear in the traceback in a specific program's situation, just let it be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any wondering, I have ended up using the following (rather obvious) solution to remind myself when debugging.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

some_dict = {} # oops a bug, this should have 'expected key'

try:
    some_dict['optional key'] # expected error
except KeyError as err:
    logger.info('Expected Error: %s', err)
    some_dict['expected key'] # unexpected error
```